# Error with dot product in Spark AR scripting for fragment shader

Tags: shader, reactive-programming, fragment-shader, spark-ar-studio

The following script silently fails when I use Reactive `less than` function whith the content of `s[0]`.
It works if I comment the following : `s[0] = R.add(s[0], R.mul(cV, cV));`.

I know that the result of above operation is correct because if I draw pixels in a texture it correctly appears.
I think it is a problem of data type, but without any warnings it's quite difficult to fix it.

Thanks for any help !

```js
const R = require('Reactive');
const S = require('Shaders');
const Textures = require('Textures');
const Diagnostics = require('Diagnostics');

Promise.all([
    Textures.findFirst('cameraTexture0')
]).then(res => {
    const cameraColor = res[0].signal;

    const uv = S.fragmentStage(S.vertexAttribute({
        'variableName': S.VertexAttribute.TEX_COORDS
    }));

    const c = S.textureSampler(cameraColor, uv);
    const cV = R.pack3(c.x, c.y, c.z);

    const s = [R.pack3(0, 0, 0)];
    s[0] = R.add(s[0], R.mul(cV, cV));

    let min_sigma2 = 100;

    const sigma2 = R.dot(s[0], R.pack3(1, 1, 1));
    Diagnostics.log('1'); // showing
    const condition = R.lt(sigma2, min_sigma2);
    Diagnostics.log('2'); // not showing
})
```

Comment: I did not run your code, but the problem seems to be that the `min_sigma2` variable has the JS data type `Number`. Reactive less than requires reactive variables as arguments. Try defining `min_sigma2` smth like `let min_sigma2 = R.val(100);`

Comment: @IgorZhurba Thanks for your response. Same result. I tried to make it using the patch editor but same issue. The result of textureSampler (RGB values) are not displayable (c.r or c.x only shows ShaderSignal info), and can not be used on other operation.

Answer (score 0):

I took a deeper look at your code. I do not know why the variable s is defined as an array, but these two lines cannot work for sure.

```
const s = [R.pack3(0, 0, 0)];
s[0] = R.add(s[0], R.mul(cV, cV));
```

The reactive variable s[0] cannot depend on itself.

Maybe you wanted to do something like this?

```
const zeroPack3 = R.pack3(0, 0, 0);
const s = R.add(zeroPack3, R.mul(cV, cV));
```

I also agree with you that the problem is most likely in the data type. You can see in more detail the real data type of the variable, for example using `Diagnostics.log (sigma2);` you can see that it is `ShaderSignal` and later it is compared with `ScalarSignal`.

Comment: Thanks for your time ! It is define as an array because in the full code (not this sample), `s` values are defined in a `for` loop. I do not understand why I am stuck with this data type, `ShaderSignal` should contains readable value.